# cannot show all content from mysql in infowindow of markers in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have project with Google Maps v3. And I have problem with showing data in infowindows of multiple marker. When I try to make infowindow for each markers, the map doesn't show at all. I'm sure I've missed something but I don't know what to do. So here is my code :

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",
        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),
        new google.maps.Point (0,0),
        new google.maps.Point (10,34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),
        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),
        new google.maps.point (12, 35));
        var map;
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.258531,-96.012599);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    <?php
    $posisi = array();
    $keterangan = array();
    foreach ($integer as $lokasi) {
    $query = "SELECT cl.locId, cl.country as country, cl.region as region, cl.city as city, cl.postalCode as postalCode, cl.latitude as latitude, cl.longitude as longitude, cl.metroCode as metroCode, cl.areaCode as areaCode
    FROM (SELECT locId as idcihuy FROM cityblocks WHERE $lokasi BETWEEN startIpNum AND endIpNum) cb, citylocation cl WHERE cb.idcihuy = cl.locId";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($location = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posisi[]= 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $location['latitude'] . ', ' . $location['longitude'] . ')';
    $keterangan[]= '(' . $location['country'] . ', ' . $location['region'] . ', ' . $location['city'] . ')';
    }
    }
    ?>
     var keterangan = new Array();
 var point = [<?php echo implode(',', $posisi) ?>];
 var lokasi = [<?php echo implode(',', $keterangan) ?>];
 var icon = pinImage;
 for (var i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
 var html = "<b>" + lokasi[i] + "</b> <br/>" + point[i];
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point[i],
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
        }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    </script>
```

And this is the HTML code (browser output) :

```
...
var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",

        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),

        new google.maps.Point (0,0),

        new google.maps.Point (10,34));

    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",

        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),

        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),

        new google.maps.point (12, 35));

        var map;

    function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.258531,-96.012599);

    var myOptions = {

    zoom: 2,

    center: myLatlng,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

         var keterangan = new Array();

     var point = [new google.maps.LatLng(20.0000, 77.0000),new google.maps.LatLng(20.0000, 77.0000),new google.maps.LatLng(38.0000, -97.0000),new google.maps.LatLng(51.7500, -1.2500)];

     var lokasi = [(IN, , ),(IN, , ),(US, , ),(GB, K2, Oxford)];

     var icon = pinImage;

     for (var i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {

      var html = "<b>" + lokasi[i] + "</b> <br/>" + point[i];

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        map: map,

        position: point[i],

        icon: pinImage,

        shadow: pinShadow

        });

        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

        }

        }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infoWindow.setContent(html);

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      });

    }

    </script>
```

Please help me o fix this problem. I really really need the help.
Thank You.

Comment: where's the exception been trowed?

Comment: sorry Mr.Jorge I don't know what you mean. Would you mind to explain to me clearly?? I'm newbie in Google Maps. Thank You.

Comment: open the browser console with f12 and see the error that appears, and try to see which line throws the error

Comment: Oke Mr.Jorge. Thanks for the explanation. I got this message from the browser console 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , tracert1.php:54
Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined tracert1.php:12
onload"

But, in that line I've never found the error before I try to add the  infowindow script. The map showed very well with multiple markers. Do I make mistakes Mr.Jorge??

Comment: watching your code and base on your error, the problem seems to be with php which are not well wrapped in your JavaScript

Comment: Mr. Jorge, for additional information the error on line 54 is for **var lokasi = [(ID, 04, Jakarta),(ID, 04, Jakarta),(ID, , ),(ID, , ),(ID, , ),(ID, , )];**. And for line 12 is for **<body onload="initialize()">**. I wish you could help me. Thank You.

Comment: Yes I think the wrong line is in the php, in **$keterangan**. Actually I want to give information about the information of each markers in Google Maps. I just want to add detail about country, region, and city from the database. So that make errors when I run the script. Apparently, the maps doesn't show at all. can you give me any suggest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalize point to `Point` in this line: (shadow) `new google.maps.Point (12, 35));`

Now you are missing quotes in the JavaScript `lokasi`, because it's not a proper array. So html never gets built.

I believe this line in PHP

```
$keterangan[]= '(' . $location['country'] . ', ' . $location['region'] . ', ' . $location['city'] . ')';
```

Should be more like this (notice the added " next to the parentheses)

```
$keterangan[]= '"(' . $location['country'] . ', ' . $location['region'] . ', ' . $location['city'] . ')"';
```

so that the Javascript looks like this

```
var lokasi = ["(IN, , )","(IN, , )","(US, , )","(GB, K2, Oxford)"];
```

Comment: OMG, Lilina. Very Thankful for your help anymore. It really works. Thanks for your patience and read my script thoroughly for answer my question. I've made mistakes because I'm still learning and stuck how to fix this. Sorry if I'm not googd speak English :)